# Subconsulta en count SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo en SQL la siguente tabla:

```
ID  Descripcion Respuesta
 1   Nombre1      True
 2   Nombre2      True
 2   Nombre2      False
 2   Nombre2      False
 1   Nombre1      True
```

Y deseo obtener en una sola tabla lo siguiente:

```
Descripcion  TotalRegistros  RegistrosSI  RegistrosNo
  Nombre1          2               2           0
  Nombre2          3               1           2
```

Por medio de esta consulta puedo obtener el total de Registros

```
SELECT Descripcion, COUNT(ID) FROM Tabla GROUP BY Descripcion, ID //Por ejemplo
```

Pero no sé cómo añadirle las demás columnas con datos, sé que si obtengo en la misma tabla el total y el total de SI puedo obtener el RegistrosNO, pero no sé como generarlo. Hay alguna forma de tener una subconsulta en el count por ejemplo?

Comment: Intenta con `SELECT COUNT(ID), ID, Descripcion, Respuesta FROM Tabla GROUP BY ID, Descripcion, Respuesta`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta =) pero en la columna de respuesta me da 0 en ambas descripciones, me faltará algo para realizar el conteo???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo de esta forma:

```
SELECT  ID,
    Descripcion, 
    COUNT(1) AS 'TotalRegistros', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Respuesta = 'True'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS 'RegistroSi', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Respuesta = 'False' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)    AS 'RegistroNO'
    FROM Tabla
    GROUP BY ID, Descripcion
```

Lo que hacemos es usar un `SUM()` condicional en función de la respuesta, si es `"True"` sumaremos 1 en `RegistroSi` y 0 en  `RegistroNo`. Si en realidad `Respuesta` es del tipo `BIT`, simplemente compararemos `Respuesta = 1`. `COUNT(1)` simplemente suma todos los casos.

Comment: Me has salvado la vidaa :) funciona perfecto, muchas gracias